# WP Ajax Action Not Picking Up Query String Parameter

Tags: ajax

Not sure why this isn't working... my action is being passed and the right function is firing from my ajax, but the callback isn't receiving my `query` parameter.

My ajax (using [bloodhound.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) running from the administrative screens, so no need to `localize`):

```
new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
  url: ajaxurl,
  prepare: function(query,settings){
    settings.url = settings.url + '?query=' + query + '&action=' + 'find_posts'
    return settings;
    }
  }
})
```

If you're not familiar with Bloodhound, the query it renders looks like this:

`admin-ajax.php?query=fdsafpasdjflkdsajkfg&action=find_posts`

Here `fdsafpasdjflkdsajkfg` is just the search string I typed in (in frustration ). So I know it is sending the correct query strings, and I also know because the error I get stems from the right action being fired.

My error is

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function esc_like() on null

It stems from this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_find_posts', 'find_posts' );

function find_posts(){
$query = $_GET['query'];
$value = '%'.$wpdb->esc_like($query).'%'; //ERROR HERE
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID, post_title 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_title LIKE %s
        ORDERBY BY ID", $value);
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    return json_encode($posts);
    wp_die();
}
```

So the question is, why is `$_GET['query'];` resolving to **`null`** when it is in my query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `global $wpdb;` in function `find_posts()`,  before you use `$wpdb`;